# Re-enable submit button if form validation fails

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form which onsubmit() validates the form contents and hides the submit button and shows an image while its processing.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() 
    {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        $('<img>').attr('src', '../images/ajax-loader.gif').insertAfter($(this));
    });
});
```

JS:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["trial"]["username"].value;
    var splitted = x.match("^(.+)@abcd\.com$");
    if (splitted != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
echo "<FORM name=\"trial\" action=\"index2.php\" method=\"POST\" onsubmit=\"return validateForm();\">";
echo "Access-Type: ";
echo "<select name=\"accesstype\" id=\"accesstype\">";
echo "<option value=\"select\">-SELECT-</option>";
echo "<option value=\"adsl\">ADSL</option>";
echo "<option value=\"cable\">CABLE</option>";
echo "</select><br><br>";
echo "<span id=\"username\" class=\"details\">Username (e.g john.smith@abcd.com) : <input id=\"username\" type=\"text\" name=\"username\" maxlength=\"40\"></span><br><br>";        
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"submit\">";
echo "</FORM>";
```

It works fine so far if all the details provided by the user meet the requirements. However, if the form validation fails, I want the submit button to re-appear for the user to be able to make the necessary changes and resubmit the form.

Comment: Re-enable it in your `validateForm()` function before returning `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just keep an image hidden and toggle display on true/false result of validation function
**HTML**

```
<form name="trial" action="index2.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">
    Access-Type: <select name="accesstype" id="accesstype">
        <option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
        <option value="adsl">ADSL</option>
        <option value="cable">CABLE</option></select>
        <br><br><span id="username" class="details">Username (e.g john.smith@abcd.com) : <input id="username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="40"></span>
        <br><br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        <img id="image" src="image_url" style="display:none" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function validateForm(form)
{
    form.submit.style.display='none';
    form.image.style.display='block';
    var x=document.forms["trial"]["username"].value;
    var splitted = x.match("^(.+)@abcd\.com$");
    if (splitted != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    form.submit.style.display='block';
    form.image.style.display='none';
    return false;
}
```

There is no need to use another click `handler` using `jQuery`, also you can't see the changes (image toggling) if validation fails because the validation will run so fast. Just check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/4YrCW/).

Answer (score 0):

declaration:

```
var me;
```

runing document ready:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
  me = $(this);  // !! no var

  ...
```

Then we can anywhere access:

```
me.css('display', 'block');
```

Other solution - matching concrete element in validation function:
(no need of `me` variable then)

```
$("input[name='submit']").toggle(splited!=null);
```

Comment: Yeah but the `me` would be out of scope.

Comment: Yes. It should be a global var. The first variation of question was shorter and has changed :/ after answer

Comment: i have only pasted one portion of the validatform it has about 7 or 8 other checks within the same function. Should i use me.css('display', 'block'); everywhere its returning false ?

Comment: You can. But it has to be declared for the global scope. (Before document ready)

Comment: so i will declare $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
  var me = $(this);

before document.ready is that correct ???

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["trial"]["username"].value;
    var splitted = x.match("^(.+)@abcd\.com$");
    if (splitted != null)
    {
        $('[name=trial]').css('display', 'none');
        return true;
    }
    $('[name=trial]').css('display', 'block');
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of ways to do this but I would avoid using the `onclick` event. 
Use `onsubmit` instead so that when the user press enter, it won't skip your handler.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    // This portion will run when the user click on the submit button or press the `enter` key
});
```